# Exception after migrating into Apache Ivy

Tags: java, spring, ivy

Getting the following console error after implementing Apache Ivy in my STS Application.

```
14:56:19,987  WARN XmlWebApplicationContext:544 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:445)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:366)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:538)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.<init>(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 24 more
14:56:20,018  INFO EhCacheManagerFactoryBean:181 - Shutting down EhCache CacheManager
14:56:20,044 ERROR ContextLoader:353 - Context initialization failed
```

i have added the following jar files :

```
    <dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.0.11.Final" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-web" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-orm" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context-support" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-test" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-oxm" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc-portlet" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-aspects" rev="4.2.1.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="joda-time" name="joda-time" rev="2.8.2" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.shiro" name="shiro-all" rev="1.2.6" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi" rev="3.14"  conf ="default" />
    <dependency org="org.apache.poi" name="poi-ooxml" rev="3.14" conf ="default" />
    <dependency org="org.apache.commons" name="commons-exec" rev="1.3" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.apache.geronimo.specs" name="geronimo-jta_1.1_spec" rev="1.1.1" conf="default"/> 
    <dependency org="javax.el" name="javax.el-api" rev="2.2.5" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.jdo" name="jdo-api" rev="3.0.1" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.servlet.jsp.jstl" name="jstl-api" rev="1.2" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.mail" name="mail" rev="1.4.7" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="javax.inject" name="javax.inject" rev="1" conf="default"/>        
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.12" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.12" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.primefaces" name="primefaces" rev="5.1" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="com.sun.faces" name="jsf-api" rev="2.1.29" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="com.sun.faces" name="jsf-impl" rev="2.1.29" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="com.google.api-client" name="google-api-client" rev="1.20.0" conf ="default" />
    <dependency org="com.google.apis" name="google-api-services-calendar" rev="v3-rev77-1.17.0-rc" conf ="default" />
    <dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.3.1" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.mnode.ical4j" name="ical4j" rev="1.0.5" conf ="default" />
    <dependency org="net.sourceforge.jexcelapi" name="jxl" rev="2.6.12" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.quartz-scheduler" name="quartz" rev="2.2.3" conf="default"/>
    <dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="2.53.1"/>
    <dependency org="com.ocpsoft" name="prettyfaces-jsf2" rev="3.3.3" conf="default"/>
     <dependency org="org.mindrot" name="jbcrypt" rev="0.3m" conf="default"/>
      <dependency org="org.omnifaces" name="omnifaces" rev="1.6.3" conf="default"/>
        <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.2.2" conf="default"/>
     <dependency org="org.mockito" name="mockito-all" rev="1.10.19" conf="default"/>
     <dependency org="org.xerial" name="sqlite-jdbc" rev="3.8.10.1" conf="default"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace you have provided, I see the following error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()`

Add the following dependencies in your pom and try again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note:**

I just checked the source code of `JsonFactory` in various versions of `jackson-core` jars. I see that the method `requiresPropertyOrdering` was first added in the version 2.3.0. So make sure you are using a version that is at least 2.3.0.

Comment: **Added the following jackson dependency. But the issues still exist.**                      <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-core" rev="2.0.1" conf="default"/>
  <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name = "jackson-databind" rev ="2.0.1" conf="default"/>
  <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-annotations" rev="2.0.1" conf="default"/>

Comment: @GjA, The version 2.0.1 is very old. Please try with 2.8.x version. I think the method `requiresPropertyOrdering` was only added to JsonFactory class from 2.6.0 onward.

Comment: @GjA, I just checked the source code of `JsonFactory` in various versions of `jackson-core` jars. I see that the method `requiresPropertyOrdering` was first added in the version 2.3.0. So make sure you are using a version that is at least 2.3.0.

Comment: **Ok!, I added  the following :**  <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-core" rev="2.8.6" conf="default"/>
   <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name = "jackson-databind" rev ="2.8.6" conf="default"/>
 <dependency org="com.fasterxml.jackson.core" name="jackson-annotations" rev="2.8.6" conf="default"/>

Comment: But no change in console error

Comment: Try with 2.6.0. It is a stable version.

Comment: @VHS I also have the same error , tried with 2.6.0 still getting console error.                     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: